# Create sub Module folders in laravel 5.1 using pingpong package

Tags: php, laravel, module, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I am developing modular project in [laravel 5.1](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1) using [pingpong](https://sky.pingpong-labs.com/docs/2.0/modules) package.Which gives me the project structure as below

```
laravel-app/
    app/
    bootstrap/
    vendor/
    modules/
      ├── Blog/
          ├── Assets/
          ├── Config/
          ├── Console/
          ├── Database/
              ├── Migrations/
              ├── Seeders/
          ├── Entities/
          ├── Http/
              ├── Controllers/
              ├── Middleware/
              ├── Requests/
              ├── routes.php
          ├── Providers/
              ├── BlogServiceProvider.php
          ├── Resources/
              ├── lang/
              ├── views/
          ├── Repositories/
          ├── Tests/
          ├── composer.json
          ├── module.json
          ├── start.php
```

I want to separate this modules folders in "admin" and "client" for differentiate my client and admin side like below,

```
laravel-app/
    app/
    bootstrap/
    vendor/
    modules/
      ├── Admin/
          ├── Blog/
              ├── Assets/
              ├── Config/
              ├── Console/
              ├── Database/
                  ├── Migrations/
                  ├── Seeders/
             ├── Entities/
             ├── Http/
                  ├── Controllers/
                  ├── Middleware/
                  ├── Requests/
                  ├── routes.php
             ├── Providers/
                 ├── BlogServiceProvider.php
             ├── Resources/
                 ├── lang/
                 ├── views/
             ├── Repositories/
             ├── Tests/
             ├── composer.json
             ├── module.json
             ├── start.php
      ├── Client/
          ├── Blog/
              ├── Assets/
              ├── Config/
              ├── Console/
              ├── Database/
                  ├── Migrations/
                  ├── Seeders/
             ├── Entities/
             ├── Http/
                  ├── Controllers/
                  ├── Middleware/
                  ├── Requests/
                  ├── routes.php
             ├── Providers/
                 ├── BlogServiceProvider.php
             ├── Resources/
                 ├── lang/
                 ├── views/
             ├── Repositories/
             ├── Tests/
             ├── composer.json
             ├── module.json
             ├── start.php
```

please help me out for this,
Thanks.

Comment: Any update about this?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:**

You can mostly achieve what you are looking for by adjusting the `config/modules.php` file, but you will have to switch it back and forth when switching between `Admin` and `Client`.

For example:

To generate (`module:make`) or use (`module:use`) modules within the `Admin` portion of your project, you will need to do the following:

In the `config/modules.php` file, adjust the `namespace` to

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Module Namespace
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Default module namespace.
|
*/

'namespace' => 'Modules\Admin',
```

In the same file, adjust the `base_path` to

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Modules path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This path used for save the generated module. This path also will added
| automatically to list of scanned folders.
|
*/

'modules' => base_path('modules/admin'),
```

That is all you need to do and calling `php artisan module:make blog` will create a Blog module within `modules/admin`.

If you need to switch between the `Admin` and the `Client` portion of your project, you will need to adjust the same two lines within the `config/modules.php` file to reflect as such.

There is one more caveat:

If you are planning to use the `Assets` folder within your modules, you will need to also adjust the corresponding line within the `config/modules.php` file, AND you will need to manually adjust a couple of methods with file paths explicitly written within your module's service provider (ex: `Admin/Blog/Providers/BlogServiceProvider.php`), AND you will need to fix your `config/view.php` - just follow the comments.

P.S. you can probably create a custom command to automate switching between `Admin` and `Client`.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already done this,but i want to create multiple modules inside the admin and client folders.

Comment: I have tried to do "php artisan module:make Admin/blog" and "php artisan module:make Client/blog" and got the desired structure,now i am working for seting routing for this structure.

Comment: Yes if u do that the folder structure is created, but then u have to go in and manually edit a bunch of things. Also, when u did that did u get an error that "admin/blog" doesn't exist or something like that? I got that error and it still created most of the folder structure but some files were missing. And if u try module:list the modules are not listed

Comment: thanks, But i want to run both the folders at the same time.

Comment: well as it is you can't really use both at the same time. you need to call module:use to switch between different modules, this just adds a step to the switching process (and like I said you can automate that process to make it even easier

Comment: that is what I want to remove if have to switch all the time than it has no use to me,because ultimately i am not using this site my customer are using this project,and i want to seperate two sides Admin and Client

Comment: you only need to switch between the two while developing. I think I may not be fully understanding what you are trying to do, I'm sorry